# Dell XPS M1530 cd stuck in drive

Tags: optical-drive, dell-xps

Yesterday I wanted to play the 1999 Unreal Tournament game that I felt nostalgiac for, but as soon as I inserted the disk, nothing happened. I've looked on all the forums and they all say the same thing. I've hit the eject button while booting up, and I've inserted a paperclip into the holes by the optical drive. There are 5 holes. 3 on the left side of the drive, and two on the right side of the drive. I NEED to get this disk out so I can install windows 7. Can anyone help???

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer that might work. He uses a spudger (or sometimes spludger). Its a tool that has a wide thin flat-head screwdriver like end that extends as a wedge, used to separate pressure fit plastic components without causing damage during separation.

"I used my metallic spudger in order to push the disk a little bit downwards (somewhere in the middle of the slot) and the optical drive did the rest. The mechanism worked and the disk came out."

Answer (score 0):

A paper clip may or maynot work depending on whether it can push the thing inside.

I always use fine needle (eg:sewing needle) in the small hole and drive gets ejected even when power supply is absent..

But u may have to check the manual or search online about which hole is drive ejecting one ..